# PHP - Upload image to multiple directories

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a form of which i am trying to upload an image to multiple directories on submit, I've got it to submit to `$target_dir` successfully, however have hit a wall when it comes to more.

I have created the variable for both directories, `$target_dir` and `$target_dir_2`

```
    session_start();
    $client = $_SESSION['clientName'] ;
    $target_dir = "../clients/" . $client . "/snippet-1/images/";
    $target_dir_2 = "../clients/" . $client . "/snippet-2/images/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["input-file-1"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

    // Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
    if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        $check = getimagesize($_FILES["input-file-1"]["tmp_name"]);
        if($check !== false) {
            echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
            $uploadOk = 1;
        } else {
            echo "File is not an image.";
            $uploadOk = 0;
        }
    }

    // Check if file already exists
    if (file_exists($target_file)) {
        echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check file size
    if ($_FILES["input-file-1"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Allow certain file formats
    if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
    && $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

    // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["input-file-1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    }
```

Comment: once it is uploaded OK to a known directory you could simply `copy` it to other directories

Comment: Where do you use second variable `$target_dir_2`? For example you can copy file in second path if the first move upload is done( [copy reference](http://fr2.php.net/copy) )

Comment: I tried using copy, however maybe i was doing it wrong. Should have added that to the question - my bad - 

this is what i tried:

`move_uploaded_file($_FILES["input-file-1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
copy($target_file, $target_dir_2);`

however this did not copy to the second location, still only the first

Comment: I have always found greater success using full paths rather than relative for these types of operations. That might be worth a try.

Comment: All that code isn't necessary to get your point across. If you only include the part with // Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";

    // if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["input-file-1"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
    }
 and the two directory variables $target_dir the question will be much easier to read.